# como posso simplificar essas duas funções?

Tags: python, funções, revisão-de-código

Este código soma as colunas e as linhas de uma matriz separadamente. Criei estas duas funções para fazer isso e preciso simplificar meu código transformando-as em uma só. Note que a única coisa que muda é de `matriz[j][i]` para `matriz[i][j]`. Existe uma maneira de chamar somente uma função mudando apenas o parâmetro?

```
def somar_linhas():
    soma = 0
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            soma = soma + matriz[i][j]
        print(f"A soma da linha {i + 1} é {soma}")
        soma = 0


def somar_colunas():
    soma = 0
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            soma = soma + matriz[j][i]
        print(f"A soma da coluna {i + 1} é {soma}")
        soma = 0


matriz = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12,], [13, 14, 15, 16]]

somar_linhas()
print()
somar_colunas()
```

Comment: Prefira passar a matriz como parâmetro das funções. Da forma que vc fez, as funções só funcionam para uma única matriz. Usando parâmetros, elas ficam mais genéricas e funcionam para qualquer matriz: https://ideone.com/AB79fi

Comment: Experimente usar o modulo numpy

Answer (score 3):

É possível simplificar e unir suas funções com o uso dum [operador condicional](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html):

```
expressão1 "if" condição "else" expressão2
```

Ele funciona testando o valor lógico da `condição` e caso:

- `condição == True` o operador condicional retorna `expressão1`.
- `condição == False` o operador condicional retorna `expressão2`.

Algumas mudanças também são benvindas como a declaração da variável soma diretamente no seu escopo de aplicação e o uso de uma [declaração de atribuição aumentada `+=`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements)

```
def somar4x4(linhas=False):    
    for i in range(4):
        soma = 0
        for j in range(4):
            soma += matriz[i][j] if linhas else matriz[j][i]
        print(f"A soma da {'linha' if linhas else 'coluna'} {i + 1} é {soma}")

matriz = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12,], [13, 14, 15, 16]]

somar4x4(linhas=True)
somar4x4(linhas=False)
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repli.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/matriz1#main.py)</sup>

Como já foi [comentado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/518681/como-posso-simplificar-essas-duas-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es#comment946934_518681) prefira passar a matriz como parâmetro da função, pois assim você faz com que o seu código se torne reaproveitável:

```
def somar4x4(m, linhas=False):    
    for i in range(4):
        soma = 0
        for j in range(4):
            soma += m[i][j] if linhas else m[j][i]
        print(f"A soma da {'linha' if linhas else 'coluna'} {i + 1} é {soma}")

matriz = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12,], [13, 14, 15, 16]]

somar4x4(matriz, linhas=True)
somar4x4(matriz, linhas=False)
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/matriz2#main.py)</sup>

Também pode ser aplicado a função embutida [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#sum) a uma [compreensão de lista](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) no laço iteração aninhado:

```
def somar4x4(m, linhas=False):
  for i in range(4):
    soma = sum([m[i][j] if linhas else m[j][i] for j in range(4)])
    print(f"A soma da {'linha' if linhas else 'coluna'} {i + 1} é {soma}")

matriz = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12,], [13, 14, 15, 16]]

somar4x4(matriz, True)
somar4x4(matriz, False)
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/matriz3#main.py)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Para criar uma função que some **ou** `linhas` **ou** `colunas`, a função deve receber um parâmetro indicando o que ela deve somar.

A partir daí, um condicional escolhe quais parâmetros somar, bem como, quais textos imprimir:

```py
def somar(colunas = False):
    soma = 0
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            if(colunas):
                soma = soma + matriz[j][i]
            else:
                soma = soma + matriz[i][j]
        if(colunas): 
            tipo = 'colunas'
            indice = j
        else:
            tipo = 'linhas'
            indice = i 
        print(f'A soma da {tipo} {indice+1} é {soma}') 
        soma = 0
    indice = 0
```

Nesta função, chamando `somar()` (sem parâmetros) ou `soma(False)` (que é padrão) será efetuada a soma das linhas.

E a chamada `somar(True)` irá efetuar a soma das colunas.